# Unpivot, Split Column, Pivot Bigquery/Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, unpivot

I have table like this:

[image: Old Table]

Then I want to change the table to this:

[image: New Table]

I usually doing this in Power BI Query Editor but the file is too big so I try in another platform like Bigquery/Postgresql

Thank you

Comment: BigQuery or Postgres? Those are two very different database products.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I prefer Bigquery, but if anyone can do it in postgres It's fine, sorry for the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below solution (for BigQuery)

```
select Fruits, regexp_extract(Store, r'Qty_(.*?)_Value') Store, Qty, Value
from your_table
unpivot (
  (Qty, Value) for 
  Store in (
    (Qty_Store_A, Value_Store_A), 
    (Qty_Store_B_C, Value_Store_B_C), 
    (Qty_Store_D_C, Value_Store_D_C)
  )
)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

And also, slightly modified version of above where you can define Store Names explicitly if for some reason RegEx way does not work for you

```
select Fruits, Store, Qty, Value
from your_table
unpivot (
  (Qty, Value) for 
  Store in (
    (Qty_Store_A, Value_Store_A) as 'Store_A', 
    (Qty_Store_B_C, Value_Store_B_C) as 'Store_B_C', 
    (Qty_Store_D_C, Value_Store_D_C) as 'Store_D_C'
  )
)
```

Obviously, with same output

Comment: thank you verymuch, I'll try it in bigquery

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join to a a values clause:

```
select t.fruits,
       u.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     values ('Store A', t.qty_store_a, t.value_store_a), 
            ('Store B', t.qty_store_b, t.value_store_b), 
            ('Store C', t.qty_store_c, t.value_store_c),
            ('Store BC', t.qty_store_bc, t.value_store_bc),
            ('Store DC', t.qty_store_dc, t.value_store_dc)
  ) as u(store, qty, value)
```

Comment: thank you for the syntax, the syntax is right. Anyway, Can you show me where can I learn the syntax? such as t.fruits and u.* thing? thank you